# c# Traer al frente formulario child en el que hago click

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Tengo un Form principal IsMdiContainer = true; en el que tengo un split container, en el panel  izquierdo un menu, en el panel 2 es donde muestro los forms hijos.
¿Cómo puedo hacer para que cuando pincho o hago click en uno de ellos (ya sea en el titulo o cualquier parte del form), me lo traiga al frente? Así poder alternan trabajo entre uno u otro según vaya necesitando.
Ahora mismo siempre se me queda uno encima de otro, a no ser que me meta directamente en un textbox para escribir.
El código con el que muestro los c hilds es:

```
private void Abro_Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Form1 formulario = new Form1();
formulario .MdiParent = this;
splitContainer.Panel2.Controls.Add(formulario );
formulario .BringToFront();
formulario .Show();
}

private void Abro_Form2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Form2 formulario = new Form2();
formulario .MdiParent = this;
splitContainer.Panel2.Controls.Add(formulario );
formulario .BringToFront();
formulario .Show();
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no entiendo, para que necesitas un MdiContainer si vas a poner los forms como parte de un Panel ? algo esta de mas. O usas MDI o usas Paneles para contener los forms es una u otra no ambas

Comment: Si te sirvió alguna respuesta puedes marcarla como correcta.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando haces click en una de las ventanas, sucede un evento. Este evento tiene que llamar a un metodo, que lleve esta ventana al frente.
Probablemente no se captura bien el evento y por ello no se lleva adelante el formulario. Hay que añadir los eventos adicionales.
Por otro lado, hay que dar el foco al formulario ".Focus()". El metodo puede ser que se llame de otra manera en Windows Forms, pero seguro tiene que estar.

Answer (score 0):

Leandro ! Muchas gracias, no me había dado cuenta que estaba haciéndolo mal, ahora mismo lo estoy invocando así:

```
Form fh = formHijo as Form;
fh.TopLevel = false;
this.splitContainer.Panel2.Controls.Add(fh);
this.splitContainer.Panel2.Tag = fh;
fh.Show();
```

Funciona perfecto de momento, gracias.
¿Crees que es mejor hacerlo así que con MdiContainer ?
Gracias Anton por la idea también.